# PhpStorm "Find In Path" defaulting to cryptic string

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Normally, using `cmd+shift+f` will launch PhpStorm's `"Find in Path..."` feature, and the search text defaults to whatever text is highlighted in the `IDE`. For me, it defaults to what is highlighted for a fraction of a second, before being replaced with this code:

`2223 2BC9 EA71 DED7 8AAE DB73 C773 21A0 E816 78AE`

I am not sure what this code represents but it is always the same. I have to delete and re-type or paste the content I want to search in order to continue with my search. The next time I open the `"Find in Path"` dialog, it happens again.

Does anyone have any clue what this might mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It must be caused by **GPG** tool: https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/51070-gpgservices-spurious-select-key-dialog.
Unchecking the box next to **OpenPGP: Insert my Fingerprint** in Mac **System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> System** should help

Comment: Amazing! I'm glad you stumbled across this question - that was a very subtle one!